# SQL Server : joins new syntax(ANSI vs. non-ANSI SQL JOIN syntax)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried to convert old MS sql join syntax to new join syntax but number of rows in the results not matching.

Original SQL:

```
select  
    b.Amount
from 
    TableA a, TableB b,TableC c, TableD d 
where 
    a.inv_no *= b.inv_no and 
    a.inv_item *= b.inv_item and 
    c.currency *= b.cash_ccy and
    d.tx_code *= b.cash_receipt
```

Converted SQL:

```
SELECT
    b.AMOUNT
FROM
    (TableA AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    TableB AS b ON a.INV_NO = b.INV_NO 
                AND a.inv_item = b.inv_item 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    TableC AS c ON c.currency = b.cash_ccy)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    TableD as d ON d.tx_code = b.cash_receipt
```

**Findings**

Results are same on both original SQL and modified SQL upto joining of 3 tables but when joining the fourth table (TableD) to the modified SQL, the number of rows returned is different.

Comment: remove the parenthesis.

Comment: What's with the brackets *`(...)`* around the first two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s?

Comment: `*` was placed on mandatory side in old-style joins. So looks like some joins have to be reversed.

Comment: What is the `*=` supposed to do?

Comment: Does this "old MS sql" syntax have a specific version or name?

Comment: There is a change for all joins to be actually `INNER`. Why would there be a row from `a` without corresponding row from `b` if you are selecting `b.amount`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of fields within predicates is important when using SQL Server's (deprecated) proprietary ANSI 89 join syntax `*=` or `=*`

So while

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableA AS A
        LEFT JOIN TableB AS B
            ON A.ColA = B.ColB;
```

Is exactly the same as

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableA AS A
        LEFT JOIN TableB AS B
            ON B.ColB = A.ColA;     -- NOTE ORDER HERE
```

The eqivalent

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableA AS A, TableB AS b
WHERE   A.ColA *= B.ColB;
```

Is not the same as

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableA AS A, TableB AS b
WHERE   B.ColA *= A.ColB;
```

This last query's ANSI 92 equivalent would be

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableA AS A
        RIGHT JOIN TableB AS B
            ON A.ColA = B.ColB;
```

Or if you dislike `RIGHT JOIN` as much as I do you would probably write:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableB AS B
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA AS A
            ON B.ColB = A.ColA;
```

So actually the equivalent query in ANSI 92 join syntax would involve starting with TableA, TableC and TableD (since these are the leading fields in the original WHERE Clause). Then since there is no direct link between the three, you end up with a cross join

```
SELECT  b.Amount
FROM    TableA AS a     
        CROSS JOIN TableD AS d
        CROSS JOIN TableC AS c
        LEFT JOIN TableB AS B
            ON c.currency = b.cash_ccy
            AND d.tx_code = b.cash_receipt
            AND a.INV_NO = b.INV_NO 
            AND a.inv_item = b.inv_item;
```

This is the equivalent rewrite, and explans the difference in the number of rows

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

*<sup>Needs to be run on SQL Server 2008 or earlier with compatibility level 80 or less</sup>*

```
-- SAMPLE DATA -- 
CREATE TABLE #TableA (Inv_No INT, Inv_item INT);
CREATE TABLE #TableB (Inv_No INT, Inv_item INT, cash_ccy INT, cash_receipt INT, Amount INT);
CREATE TABLE #TableC (currency INT);
CREATE TABLE #TableD (tx_code INT);

INSERT #TableA (inv_no, inv_item) VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2);
INSERT #TableB (inv_no, inv_item, cash_ccy, cash_receipt, Amount) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2);
INSERT #TableC (currency) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);
INSERT #TableD (tx_code) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);

-- ORIGINAL QUERY(32 ROWS)
SELECT  
    b.Amount
FROM 
    #TableA a, #TableB b,#TableC c, #TableD d 
WHERE 
    a.inv_no *= b.inv_no and 
    a.inv_item *= b.inv_item and 
    c.currency *= b.cash_ccy and
    d.tx_code *= b.cash_receipt

-- INCORRECT ANSI 92 REWRITE (2 ROWS)
SELECT  b.AMOUNT
FROM    #TableA AS a 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN #TableB AS b 
            ON a.INV_NO = b.INV_NO 
            and a.inv_item = b.inv_item 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN #TableC AS c 
            ON c.currency = b.cash_ccy
        LEFT OUTER JOIN #TableD as d 
            ON d.tx_code = b.cash_receipt;


-- CORRECT ANSI 92 REWRITE (32 ROWS)
SELECT  b.Amount
FROM    #TableA AS a        
        CROSS JOIN #TableD AS d
        CROSS JOIN #TableC AS c
        LEFT JOIN #TableB AS B
            ON c.currency = b.cash_ccy
            AND d.tx_code = b.cash_receipt
            AND a.INV_NO = b.INV_NO 
            AND a.inv_item = b.inv_item;
```

Comment: Can that query be simplified into something less janky looking?

Comment: @JoePhilllips It's really more of a problem of the original query being kind of insane. You kind of want to rewrite the whole thing from scratch, with the understanding of what exactly the original query was trying to do, something we don't know well enough. This is basically a "machine translation" - it produces the same results, but it's kind of ugly.